# monkeyrunner easy.By viewid

Tags: android, monkeyrunner

I have android activity with options menu with id as R.id.createRepository.  Now I want to use monkey runner to send touch event to it.  I need to get the view id and I tried below code:

```
from com.android.monkeyrunner import MonkeyRunner, MonkeyDevice  
from com.android.monkeyrunner.easy import EasyMonkeyDevice, By  

device = MonkeyRunner.waitForConnection()  
easy_device = EasyMonkeyDevice(device)  

# Start your android app

# touch the view by id

easy_device.touch(By.id('id/createRepository'), MonkeyDevice.DOWN_AND_UP) # in activity java code I can refer to it as R.id.createRepository and I have even tried passing it in
```

but moneyrunner cannot find the view.  I need help to define correct view id.

Regards,

Miten

Answer (score 2):

You can use the uiautomatorviewer to find the id of the view. It's a tool located in the android-sdk folder under tools.

Just open your app in the screen where the view with the unknown id is located. Then open the uiautomatorviewer and take a screenshot. You will find the app layout with all the view details.